# TWILIO API ERROR Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient django

Tags: python, django, api, twilio

I am trying to include TWILIO API to my project. It should send sms. I have finished tutorial, but then i get error *Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient*. I have credentials in .env file and then i try to import them to settings and then get this credentials from settings to views.

This is when i get error.

.env

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TWILIO_NUMBER= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

settings.py

```
import os

    TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = os.getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
    TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = os.getenv('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
    TWILIO_NUMBER = os.getenv('TWILIO_NUMBER')
    SMS_BROADCAST_TO_NUMBERS = [
        '+111111111', 
    ]
```

views

```
from django.conf import settings                                                                                                                                                       
from django.http import HttpResponse
from twilio.rest import Client


def broadcast_sms(request):
    message_to_broadcast = ("Have you played the incredible TwilioQuest "
                                                "yet? Grab it here: https://www.twilio.com/quest")
    client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    for recipient in settings.SMS_BROADCAST_TO_NUMBERS:
        if recipient:
            client.messages.create(to=recipient,
                                   from_=settings.TWILIO_NUMBER,
                                   body=message_to_broadcast)
    return HttpResponse("messages sent!", 200)
```

and here is when code work, but i want to import this from settings..

```
# def sms(request):
#     TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#     TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#     TWILIO_NUMBER = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#     message_to_broadcast = ("Have you played the incredible TwilioQuest "
#                                                 "yet? Grab it here: https://www.twilio.com/quest")
#
#     client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
#     for recipient in settings.SMS_BROADCAST_TO_NUMBERS:
#         if recipient:
#             client.messages.create(to=+xxxxxxxxx,
#                                    from_=+xxxxxxxxxx,
#                                    body=message_to_broadcast)
#     return HttpResponse("messages sent!", 200)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are using a .env file rather than setting your OS's environmental variables? If so, there is and article below, pointing to https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv.

[How To Set Environment Variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html)

Comment: Hi, i have set up environmental variables like in the article, but i get same error still. Should i change something in settings as well?

Comment: When you run the echo command in the article, do you see the values?

Comment: yes, I have checked and this returns values. I am wondering if this thr only thing i should do? cause i have still this os.getenv in settings file. maybe i should import this values to django in some way?

Comment: Try a small Python program outside using a framework, to see if that works as expected, so you can narrow down the issue.

Comment: at the end it helped to install env library, but self django could not read environment values directly from computer.