# Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient

Tags: python, twilio, message, whatsapp

I want to send whatsapp messages using python using the **Twilio** module. I got a code from youtube and when ran the code ,it came with an error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatsapp.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = Client()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line
54, in __init__
    raise TwilioException("Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient")
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioException: Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient
```

Here is my code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client()

from_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp: +60***86744'
to_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp: +8134***727'

client.messages.create(body='Testing message using python',
                       from_ = from_whatsapp_number,
                       to = to_whatsapp_number)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TWILIO API ERROR Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042648/twilio-api-error-credentials-are-required-to-create-a-twilioclient-django)

Comment: Twilio want's your "API key", or client ID.

Comment: If you leave the Client parameters blank, it assumed you have the Account SID and Auth Token configured in your environment - https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-python/index.html

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python), a `Client` should be declared as follows:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
```

You were missing your `account_sid` and `auth_token` when you declared your `Client`.
As @Alan pointed out, if `account_sid` and `auth_token` are not declared in the `Client`, Twilio looks for them as environment variables, `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` respectively.